# Hide current and open previous on ciick?

Tags: angular

So I have multiple divs that I open and hide on click. What I want is to have a back button so when the user clicks it to hide that current div and open previous. Any suggestion how can I do that? I show and hide div with boolean variable `true`-`false`. Something like history, but they are all on the same page.

```
<div *ngIf="visible = !visible"></div>
<div *ngIf="visible1 = !visible1"></div>
<div *ngIf="visible2 = !visible2"></div>
<div *ngIf="visible3 = !visible3"></div>
```

Example: If I want to show the content of `div 3` I can come from `div 2` `div 1` and `div 4`. So I want to remember what div I came so when I hit back button to hide it and open that div.

Comment: why not add a `(click)` handler ? please clarify a bit more on what you want to achieve ?

Comment: how will i rememmber from what div he came ? imagine it like history back button...here is all on same page and show/hide divs.

Comment: You can pass in a unique parameter in the `(click)` event handler for each div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `array` where you keep track of which divs are getting clicked/hidden. Then, when back button is clicked, you can do a pop to get the last added div. That returned value can used to display the div.

Sample code:

```
<div *ngIf="visible1 == true" (click)="visible1 = false; addToHistory('visible1')" 
           style="width: 400px; height: 50px; background: skyblue; margin-bottom: 5px">
           Div 1
</div>
```

componet.ts

```
history = [];

  visible1 = true;
  visible2 = true;
  visible3 = true;
  visible4 = true;

  constructor() {
  }

  addToHistory(value){
    this.history.push(value);
  }

  getFromHistory(){
    let x = this.history.pop();

    if(x == 'visible1'){
      this.visible1 = true;
    }
    if(x == 'visible2'){
      this.visible2 = true;
    }
    if(x == 'visible3'){
      this.visible3 = true;
    }
    if(x == 'visible4'){
      this.visible4 = true;
    }
  }
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ovPPIzIpHD6eGnumKEKH?p=preview)